# Software or method to batch invert b/w images

Tags: ubuntu, image-processing, ocr

I have directories of 100-500 small black & white image files (jpg) that I need to batch invert, from white text on black to black text on white. They will then be input to tesseract-ocr.
I am looking for software or some method on Ubuntu 16.04 to do this. Maybe tesseract has such a function?

I found this: [How to invert colors in multiple images using Gimp in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/541960/234752) which seems to be the right idea, but it is an old answer and the link is dead. When I searched on "Batch Image Manipulation Plugin" I found it but only for Windows (I only have Gimp installed on Ubuntu).

I have seen some solutions using imagemagick, but it doesn't seem to run on my system, so I would rather avoid those for now.

This doesn't seem so difficult, but so far I haven't found anything that can do batch processing. I am not a Linux expert so if it isn't a GUI or command line solution I may need a detailed instruction.

A Windows 7 solution may be ok if no other option.

I am looking for a no-cost solution if possible.

Comment: Standard JPEGs use three 8-bit channels. Are you sure you really have 1-bit (black-and-white) or 2-bit (four-color) JPEGs? They may be stored as 24 bits (three 8-bit channels) even if they appear monochrome.

Comment: @Kodiologist You are right. I deleted that part. The basic point was that they are b/w and not gray scale.

Comment: Okay. Because of JPEG compression artifacts, they'll have a lot of gray pixels even though they're supposed to be monochrome, so I would recommend thresholding them to true black and white before inverting, and make sure to save in a lossless format such as PNG. An indexed PNG will probably be smaller than the original JPEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with python and have PIL or Pillow installed then the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498875/how-to-invert-colors-of-image-with-pil-python-imaging is a way to go.

You can add in a glob to find all of your images.

Something like:

`from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
from glob import glob
import os
os.chdir('Documents/')  # Obviously this needs to be the top directory of your image tree
file_list = glob("**/*.jpg", recursive=True) # Get the filenames
outdir = "Converted"  # You can set this to what you like
for fname in file_list:  # For each filename
    image = Image.open(fname)  # Read it as an image
    image=image.convert('L')  # Make sure it is gray-scale
    image=ImageOps.invert(image)  # invert it
    newname = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.split(fname)[-1])  # Create a new name
    print("Saving Inverted", fname, "as", newname) 
    image.save(newname)  # Save it`

Comment: I installed python-pil and tried the script in the top answer, but got an error. I put the result on [Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TqjdjqM6yJ/). Maybe I'm missing something? Also I would need to know how to code the loop.

Comment: @user3169 Added working code that just needs the directory names changed to fit you ones, _note that it assumes that each filename is unique_, it does not overwrite the existing files.

Comment: Thanks. It works as advertised. Due to the number of commands, I would like to consider a shell script to run it. I wrote one (basically yours above with #!/bin/python3.5 as the first line), marked it as executable but no run option on double-click and couldn't run in terminal. No doubt I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The recommended shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the first line _a `#encoding utf-8` second line is usually recommended_

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is my/the goto for all batch processing of images.

- Open Source
- Cross Platform

Using with the Linux `find` command, *(**Warning**: This will invert in-place every image it finds)*:

```
cd the_top_dir_of_your_image_tree
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec magick mogrify -negate {};
```

Note that some versions of ImageMagick install `convert` and `mogrify` as distinct tools while others have a `magick` with sub-commands.

Comment: That was my first thought as well; but does it support "invert"? If so, could you please include this with your answer?

Comment: Look at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#negate

Comment: Perhaps. I have never used ImageMagick before, but it might be overkill for what I am trying to do. At the least I would need some detailed instructions how to. I can ask that on SO if it would be a more appropriate site.

Comment: @user3169 , Ring gave you a self sufficient pointer to the docs with an example right there, it is as simple as `convert blackandwhite.jpg -negate whiteandblack.jpg` for one file . The only additional thing you need is to loop over your files and feed them to convert. Look for examples of find + xargs

Comment: @AnonymousLurker OK, I got it. Guess I was trying to make it more complicated than it was. All I need now is to figure out how to loop through the files. Sorry, I am computer literate but not a scripting expert. I may need more help.

Comment: @user3169: Example of using find and mogrify to modify in place, (overwriting the files), added.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the example but got an error, "find: missing argument to `-exec' ". I could execute for testing purposes "mogrify -format png 01.jpeg" and it worked as expected. But when I checked the options for mogrify online, there was no -invert option.

Comment: @user3169 - the option is now -negate rather than invert - editing the above.